# What will be benefit of surrogate key in data warehosue layer?

Tags: etl, data-warehouse

OLTP source tables are having surrogate keys (numeric values) and natural keys (alphanumeric values), then can I skip creating surrogate keys in target OLAP DB (Dimensional Model) for dimension tables. 
I know that I will need surrogate keys for fact tables as unique key for fact table will be a large set and I will need a single columns with numeric values as primary key there.
I am joining multiple source tables for populating data into one dimension target then I am wondering to use unique id (numeric values) of driving table (this id is inherited from OLTP source) as primary key , provided that data granularity of resulted record is at driving tables' id level (resulted record is the record after main source driving table is joined with other source tables).

What will be benefit of surrogate key in data warehouse layer?

Thanks,
Rajneesh

Comment: Pls refer to Wikipedia on advantages of surrogate key - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key I think now a days surrogate key concept is replaced by smart key. Its better and close to your idea. Its like instead of ETL generated numeric values, its unique values from source + source system to make them unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, surrogate key is an artificial key that is used as a substitute for natural key (NK) defined in data warehouse tables. We can use natural key or business keys as a primary key for tables.

These are some of the benefits of surrogate keys

1. Surrogate keys help protect the Datawarehouse system from unexpected
   administrative changes
2. Surrogate keys allow the Datawarehouse system to integrate the same data.
3. Surrogate keys enable you to add rows to dimensions that do not
   exist in the source system
4. Surrogate keys provide the means for tracking changes in dimension
   attributes over time
5. Integer surrogate keys can improve query and processing performance
   compared to larger character or GUID keys

Answer (score 0):

Closing the loop as Koushik Roy has answered this.
Adding additional references with hope it may be helpful for community:
 https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5431/surrogate-key-vs-natural-key-differences-and-when-to-use-in-sql-server/

https://dwgeek.com/data-warehouse-surrogate-key-design-advantages-disadvantages.html/